# How to limit foreach for multiple table as a one

Tags: php, foreach

I have the issue with `LIMIT` with `foreach` using PHP.

**Basics:** I have 50 different tables and in every table I have 2 rows.

When I try to add `LIMIT 1` to `$$modules_for_all`, then I see 50 rows, but I want to see only 1. If I add `LIMIT 2`, then I see 100 rows.

How I can connect all these tables as a one `LIMIT 1` to get 1 row in foreach?

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {

  // $array_table_name contains names with tables
  $table_names = $array_table_name[$i];

  $modules_for_all = 'g_module_for_all_'.$i;
  $$modules_for_all = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT * FROM $table_names WHERE user='1' LIMIT 1");

}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {

  $modules_for_from = ${"g_module_for_all_$i"};

  foreach ($modules_for_from as $m_foreach_as) {

    echo $m_foreach_as['id'];

  }

}
```

Example tables:

```
table_1
id   date_added
1    2018-12-01 00:00:00
2    2018-12-02 00:00:00

table_2
id   date_added
1    2018-12-03 00:00:00
2    2018-12-04 00:00:00

table_3
id   date_added
1    2018-12-05 00:00:00
2    2018-12-06 00:00:00
```

Example foreach:

```
<?php
$array_table_name_1 = 'table_1';
$array_table_name_2 = 'table_2';
$array_table_name_3 = 'table_3';

$for_table_1 = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT * FROM $array_table_name_1 WHERE id='1' LIMIT 1 ORDER BY date_added");
$for_table_2 = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT * FROM $array_table_name_2 WHERE id='1' LIMIT 1 ORDER BY date_added");
$for_table_3 = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT * FROM $array_table_name_3 WHERE id='1' LIMIT 1 ORDER BY date_added");

foreach ($for_table_1 as $m_foreach_as) {
  echo $m_foreach_as['id'];
}

foreach ($for_table_2 as $m_foreach_as) {
  echo $m_foreach_as['id'];
}

foreach ($for_table_3 as $m_foreach_as) {
  echo $m_foreach_as['id'];
}

// Now result is '111' but I want only '1' (realted to make LIMIT 1 to all foreach)
```

Comment: The LIMIT is executed for every table you have. If you want to see only one row, then you will have to use the query only once instead of 50 times.

Comment: @Rafael Well, that is what I asked about. How I can achieve that?

Comment: Well, not using the **for** loop and executing it once only?

Comment: @Rafael Could you show me an example for 50 tables?

Comment: JohnSmth, can you write down the structure of two tables you have and expected result you want with limit 1? What you are asking to be done while looping through 50 tables to output one row using limit is not possible. You might want to work on a way to rephrase what it is you want as a result.

Comment: How do you decide which one row out of the 50 tables you want to see?

Comment: @Rafael I created for you example in the answer.

Comment: @Nick using `ORDER BY date_added`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to connect the tables is by using a `UNION`. So you will need to build one large `UNION` query and then perform the select after the loop:

```
$tables = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {  
  // $array_table_name contains names with tables
  $table_names = $array_table_name[$i];
  $tables[] = "(SELECT * FROM $table_names WHERE user='1')";    
}
$query = implode(" UNION ", $tables) . " ORDER BY date_added LIMIT 1";
$result = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll($query);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna have to use UNION ALL for summing this rows together before ordering and limiting the results.

But keep in mind that a query like this will **only work** if all the tables in your array have the **same** structure. If they do not, then you will have to be specific in the query to make them have the same fields.

```
$array_table_name = [
    'table_1',
    'table_2',
    'table_3',
];

$search_id = 1;

$selectsArray = [];
foreach ($array_table_name as $table_name) {
    $selectsArray[] = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id='$search_id'\n";
}
```

As you see, I am using `foreach()` and not `for()` so you won't update the for by decreasing/increasing the number of tables in the array. So to finally have:

```
$selectsUnion = implode("UNION ALL\n", $selectsArray) . "ORDER BY date_added \nLIMIT 1";
```

You can see the code tested and query mounted here: https://3v4l.org/HXH2K

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this: `foreach ($modules_for_from as $m_foreach_as) if ($tmp++ < 1) {`

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?

Comment: That doesn't explain much of anything, John.